# Forming a graph

Tags: graph-theory

I'm trying to apply graph theory tools to a problem I'm working on, but am not sure it's possible to construct what I need.  This isn't the whole problem, but the sticky part is this: I have three sets of things and I need to select exactly two things with at most one from any set. For example, if my sets are (AB), (C), (D), my options are AC, AD, BC, BD, CD. I need to construct the graph so that node disjoint paths will not have duplicate elements. If I just write out these options as nodes, for example, one path could have AC in it and another AD. This won't work because A is selected in both paths. Anyone know of a clever way to construct a graph where node (vertex) disjoint paths can never share elements? I was trying to add dummy nodes to constrain the options but have had no luck yet.

Answer (score 1):

If your graph contains a path of length $2$, it's always going to have two edges that share and endpoint.

[image: path of length 2]

The red and blue edges above share an endpoint.  The only graphs without this property are formed by the union of $K_2$ subgraphs and isolated vertices.

---

You appear to be seeking something along the lines of a tripartite graph:

[image: tripartite graph]

In this example, the three parts are $\{A,B\}$, $\{C\}$ and $\{D\}$, and we draw an edge between any two vertices from different parts.  Any edge in the graph represents a choice of two elements from distinct parts.

Alternatively, we could represent each part with a disjoint clique:

[image: union of cliques]

And you are seeking [independent sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_%28graph_theory%29) of size $2$ in this graph.